# JavaScript Temperature Conversion Function won't work

Tags: javascript, function, object

So I am attempting to create a temperature conversion function that takes in an object (var temperature) with a numerical temp property and a Fahrenheit- or Celsius-denoting property as a parameter, but when I alert the function later it just returns [object Object]. I was not sure how to access the specific properties within temperature because it says they are undefined if I do not use a for...in loop. Below is my best attempt at getting the function to return an object that contains the converted numerical temperature value as well as the changed tempUnits property value. Thanks for the help!

```
var temperature = {
    temp: 75,
    tempUnits: "f" // means Fahrenheit (°F) or Celsius (°C), °F here. 
};
// (°F - 32) * (5/9) = °C
// (°C) * (9/5) + (32) = °F 
var convertTemperature = function (object) {
    for (var prop in object) {
        if (object[prop] === "f") {
            var temperatureC = {
                temp: (((object[prop]) - 32) * (5 / 9)),
                tempUnits: "c"
            };
            return temperatureC;
        } else if (object[prop] === "c") {
            var temperatureF = {
                temp: (((object[prop]) * (9 / 5)) + 32),
                tempUnits: "f"
            };
            return temperatureF; 
        }
    }
};

alert(convertTemperature(temperature)); // returns [object Object]
```

Comment: I think you mean `object.tempUnits === 'f'`?

Comment: You don't need a loop. Just say _object.temp_ and _object.tempUnits_ to access the properties in your function, and _alert(convertTemperature(temperature).temp)_ to display the result. Have a look at the MDN article [Working With Objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're doing it in a really odd, roundabout way:

```
var temperature = {
    temp: 75,
    tempUnits: "f" // means Fahrenheit (°F) or Celsius (°C), °F here. 
};
// (°F - 32) * (5/9) = °C
// (°C) * (9/5) + (32) = °F 
var convertTemperature = function (o) {
    var val = o.temp;
    if (o.tempUnits === 'f') {
        return temperatureC = {
            temp: ((val - 32) * (5 / 9)),
            tempUnits: "c"
        };
    } else {
        return {
            temp: ((temp * (9 / 5)) + 32),
            tempUnits: "f"
        };
    }
};

var o = convertTemperature(temperature);
alert(o.temp + ' ' + o.tempUnits);
```

Answer (score 1):

Another fun example of JavaScript type coercion obscuring the nature of an error for neophytes!

Any time you see `"[object Object]"` in your JS program's output, you have a type mismatch where a non-primitive object has been put somewhere that was expecting a string (unless you wanted to see `"[object Object]"` specifically).  In your case, `convertTemperature` returns an object; `alert` expects a string.  Sadly, instead of raising some sort of red flag, `alert` silently coerces your object (or number, or what have you) into a string.  Unless you override `toString` on your object, it will always be coerced to `"[object Object]"`.

It appears the root of your problem, though, is fundamental misunderstanding of object syntax in JS.  If you posted the code that resulted in your choice to introduce a `for` loop, I am sure we would see an obvious (to JS veterans) error that caused the problem in the first place.  I'm going to bet that you tried something like:

```
if (temperature[tempUnits] === "f") {
```

The correct syntax for accessing a property named `tempUnits` of an object named `temperature` is `temperature.tempUnits` or the exactly equivalent `temperature["tempUnits"]`.  When you write `temperature[tempUnits]`, JS thinks you have some other variable named `tempUnits` whose *value* you are trying to use as a property name.  Since there is no such variable, the value of `tempUnits` is `undefined` - which is not a property of `temperature`.

Answer (score 0):

In the last line of:

```
var convertTemperature = function (object) {
    for (var prop in object) {
        if (object[prop] === "f") {
            var temperatureC = {
                temp: (((object[prop]) - 32) * (5 / 9)),
```

the value of `object[prop]` is `'f'`. What you want is `object['temp']` or just `object.temp`.

Since you are passing an object with fixed property names, just do:

```
function convertTemperature(obj) {
  if (obj.tempUnits == 'f') {
    return {temp: (obj.temp - 32) * 5 / 9, tempUnits: 'c'};
  }
  return {temp: obj.temp * 9 / 5 + 32, tempUnits: 'f'};
}

alert(convertTemperature({temp:212,tempUnits:'f'}).temp); // 100
```